# How to test a function inside a functional component like OnFinish, and update etc

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs

I have a component Template. Inside the Template component I defined another two functions. I want to test **onFinish, updateProviderEmailTemplate** functions using jest, enzyme but I don't test it. Can anyone help me how I can test those functions inside the template component. In class component I used to test those instance but I don't know how to test it using functional component.

```
 const Template = () => {
  const { isLoading, placeholderList, templateData } = useTemplateData(
    new ProviderEmailTemplateService()
  );

  const [convertedContent, setConvertedContent] = useState(null);
  const providerEmailTemplateService = new ProviderEmailTemplateService();

  const updateProviderEmailTemplate = async (id, subject, content) => {
    try {
      const response = await providerEmailTemplateService.updateProviderEmailTemplate(
        id,
        subject,
        content
      );
      notificationHelper("success", uiLabel.SUCCESS_TITLE, response.message);
    } catch (error) {
      notificationHelper("error", uiLabel.ERROR_TITLE, error.message);
    }
  };

  const onFinish = async () => {
    if (convertedContent === templateData.content) return;
    updateProviderEmailTemplate(
      templateData.id,
      templateData.subject,
      convertedContent
    );
  };

  return (
    <div className="template">
      <Form name="basic" onFinish={onFinish}>
        {templateData &&
        templateData?.content &&
        !isLoading &&
        placeholderList.length !== 0 ? (
          <>
            <CustomEditor
              setConvertedContent={setConvertedContent}
              content={templateData.content}
              placeholderList={[
                <CustomEditorToolBar
                  optionList={[...placeholderList]}
                  toolBarName="Insert field"
                />,
              ]}
            />
          </>
        ) : (
          <LoadingSpinner isShowing={isLoading} />
        )}
        <Form.Item>
          <div className="d-flex justify-content-end">
            <Button type="primary" htmlType="submit">
              Save
            </Button>
          </div>
        </Form.Item>
      </Form>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Template;
```

Comment: Is `onFinish` triggered when the form is submitted? You could exercise `onFinish` (and by extension, `updateProviderEmailTemplate`) by submitting the form. Mock `providerEmailTemplateService` and spy on its invocation.

Comment: Could you please give me some idea. How do I do that. Please help with writing code.

Comment: *enzyme but I don't test it. Can anyone help me how I can test those functions inside the template component* - this is the reason why Enzyme isn't the best tool for that. React Testing Library is preferred to test functional components.

Comment: Can you give me a solution code so that I can understand. @EstusFlask

Comment: Requests to write the code for you aren't well-received on SO because it's Q&A community and not code-writing service. Consider checking React Testing Library documentation for examples and re-asking the question if you have specific problems with the implementation.